# How to compare two standard conversion sequences use the rank of contained conversions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>
void g(int*);  //#1
void g(int (&arr)[2]);  //#2

void f(int*);  //#3
void f(int const*);  //#4
int main(){
  int arr[2] ={0};
  f(arr);    // choose #3
  g(arr);  //ambiguous
}
```

Consider the above code, **#3** is seleteced for `f(ptr)`, however, `g(arr)` gives a `ambiguous` diagnostic.

The rule for choosing the best function is defined as:

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if
>
> > - S1 is a proper subsequence of S2 (comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form defined by [over.ics.scs], excluding any Lvalue Transformation; **the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence**) or, if not that

So take a look at [over.ics.scs#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.scs#3)

> These are used to rank standard conversion sequences. The rank of a conversion sequence is determined by considering the rank of each conversion in the sequence and the rank of any reference binding.

According to my understanding of the above rule, I can understand why `#3` is the best overload for `f(ptr)`, that is:

Given S1 as (arr => int*):

```
Array-to-pointer conversion -> (identity conversion)  
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                   
     int[2] => int*             int* => int*
```

while given S2 as (ptr => int const*)

```
Array-to-pointer conversion -> Qualification conversions ->  identity conversion   
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
     int[2] => int*               int* => int const*           int const* => int const*
```

Since  `identity conversion` is a proper subsequence of `Qualification conversions`, hence S1 is better than S2. So, **#3** is selected by overload resolution for `f(ptr)`.

When I use a similar process to determine which is best for `g(arr)`, I encounter an issue.

Again, given S1 as (arr => int*)

```
Array-to-pointer conversion -> identity conversion  
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
      int[2] => int*              int* => int*
```

while given S2 as(arr => int (&arr)[2])

> When a parameter of reference type binds directly to an argument expression, the implicit conversion sequence is the identity conversion, unless the argument expression has a type that is a derived class of the parameter type, in which case the implicit conversion sequence is a derived-to-base Conversion

```
identity conversion
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  bind to reference
```

Here, `identity conversion` of `S2` is a proper subsequence of `Array-to-pointer conversion` of `S1`, hence it should be better than `S1`, why the compiler complained `g(arr)` is an ambiguous invocation?

Do I have any misreading about how to rank the standard conversion sequences? How to compare two standard ICS (rank of the contained conversion)?

Comment: The target example uses function templates, but the same ics ranking rules apply to the instantiated functions.

Comment: @cigien The example does not interpret this question. Although they all have exact rank, however identity conversion is better than any other conversion that has exact rank. Otherwise, why `f(ptr)` is non-ambigous, Doesn't `qualification conversion` have an **exact rank** ?

Comment: To clarify, you're asking why the call `g(arr);` is ambiguous, is that right? Or are you looking for a response that specifically addresses your understanding of the rules?

Comment: @cigien Both.  In my opinion,  each conversion in `f(arr);` and in `g(arr);` all only contain the conversion with **exact rank**, but why `g(arr); ` is ambiguous. I need the interpretation for these issues.

Comment: Ah, ok. There's probably a target for why `f(arr)` is not ambiguous, but I'll reopen the question anyway.

Comment: @cigien Thanks. My argument here is if **identity conversion** is not better than any other conversion(no identity conversion) that has **exact rank**, then `f(arr)` would also be ambiguous.  And the rule also says that "the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence"

Comment: @cigien And I don't think the answers to that question give a complete interpretation, as I said, see http://eel.is/c++draft/tab:over.ics.scs, **Qualification conversions** also has `exact Match rank`. If use the interpretation of the answers, S1 contains `Qualification conversions` is not distinguishable with S2 contains `Ientity conversion`, namely, `f(arr)`  ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

The key point is here:

> S1 is a proper subsequence of S2 (comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form defined by [over.ics.scs], **excluding any Lvalue Transformation**; the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence) or, if not that

That means, for function call `g(arr)`, all **Array-to-pointer conversion** are not used to determine the rank. In other words, from type `int[2]` to type `int*`, there's only an identity conversion that used to determine the rank. Hence, S1 of `void g(int*);` and S2 of `void g(int (&arr)[2]);` are indistinguishable ICS, hence the compiler gives an ambiguous error.

As a contrast, the conversions for `void f(int*);` and `void f(int const*);` used to compare rank are  `identity conversion` and `qualification conversion`, respectively.

According to the rule:

> **the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence**

Hence, `Qualification conversion` is considered to have a worse rank than that of `identity conversion`. So, `void f(int*)` wined the competition.

Comment: No, *qualification conversion*, which is in the *Qualification adjustment* category has the same rank as *Identity*. Both of them are ranked as an *Exact match*.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to apply [over.ics.rank-3.2.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.rank-3.2.1) to these overload sets, but this rule doesn't apply for either `f` or `g`.

---

Given the call `f(arr);`, when performing overload resolution for `f`, both overloads require a standard conversion sequence consisting of an *Array-to-pointer* conversion, and both have the same rank, which is *Exact Match*. The tie breaker used in this case is [over.match.best#over.ics.rank-3.2.5](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.rank-3.2.5):

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if
>
> ...
>
> > S1 and S2 differ only in their qualification conversion ([conv.qual]) and yield similar types T1 and T2, respectively, where T1 can be converted to T2 by a qualification conversion.

There's an example following this rule that demonstrates how the rule works.

For the overload set `f`, `T1` is `int *` and `T2` is `int const *`, and `T1` can be converted to `T2` by a qualification conversion.

---

In the case of the call `g(arr);`, when performing overload resolution, the overload `g(int (&)[2])` is ranked as an *Exact match*, since the standard conversion sequence needed is a *No Conversion Required*.

However, the overload `g(int*)` is also ranked as an *Exact match*, since the standard conversion sequence needed is an *Array-to-Pointer* conversion.

Unlike for `f` however, there is no rule in [over.ics.rank] that disambiguates between the standard conversion sequences for `g`, and the call fails.

Comment: Could you tell me what case does "S1 is a proper subsequence" apply to?

Comment: @jackX Probably, but I'll have to think about it for a bit. Regardless, that would be a separate question that I don't really want to discuss in the comments.

Comment: Reback to this question,  "S1 and S2 differ only in their qualification conversion",   however, S1 does not contain `qualification conversion` instead  S2 contains a `qualification conversion`. The cited rule seems to say `S1` and `S2` both contain `qualification conversion`s  that are different.

Comment: see [this case](https://godbolt.org/z/3P3oTb), `qualification conversion`(eliminate the vague of whether identity conversion is a qualification conversion) can not give a privilege power to this case(**Function pointer conversion** absolutely has exact match rank ) any more. Here is **Identity conversion** versus **Function pointer conversion**. IMO, [over.ics.rank#3.2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3.2.1) apply to here.

Comment: "*The cited rule seems to say S1 and S2 both contain qualification conversions that are different.*" Not really, it's just that one can be converted to the other. Also, I'm not sure your demo applies: `noexcept` specifiers aren't allowed to be added as a *qualification conversion* as far as I'm aware.

Comment: S1 and S2 differ only **in their qualification conversion**.  Decomposite this sentence,  S1 has a qualification named  `qc1` while  S2 has a qualification named `qc2`,  `qc1` is different with `qc2`, then this rule will apply to.  In my example `qc1` is a identity conversion rather than qualification conversion(int* => int*).

Comment: That demontraste is taken to prove  `Identity conversion` has a greater rank than `function pointer conversion`(which has a exact match rank).  Otherwise, it would be ambiguous.

Comment: Take a look at the example in [over.ics.rank-3.2.5]. The only difference in the overloads is the volatile qualification. One can be converted to another by *adding* a qualifier. The qualifiers don't have to be completely different for the rule to apply.

Comment: I didn't say the qualifier shall be the same.  I said S1 and S2 all have a qualification conversion.  In that example,  S1 has a qualification conversion that converts  `int*`  to `int const*` ,  S2 has a qualification  conversion that  converts  `int*` to  `int const  volatile *`, the former is similar with  the latter, and can be converted to, hence that rule  applies to.  Instead  `int*` to `int*` is not a qualification conversion.  And  look at my demo,  it  definitely proves  `Identity conversion ` has a greater rank than other conversion that has  exact match rank.

Comment: Except for [over.ics.rank#3.2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3.2.1), there' no special rule that gives the privilege to  function  `void  g(void (*ptr)() noexcept)`.

Comment: As I said, I don't think `noexcept` specifiers are considered in qualification conversions. If you want to talk about that, you should make a separate question I think.

Comment: My meaning is , we  consider a example that does not have `qualification conversion`(without the potentially effect of over.match.best#over.ics.rank-3.2.5, eliminate the interference), and the  example only has  **Identity conversion**  and **Function pointer conversion**,  only such two conversions are respectively contained by two ICS which will be ranked.  That will prove  over.ics.rank-3.2.1 is  applying here.

Comment: I have knew what is the divergence we have. You think from `int*` to `int*` can be considered as a qualification conversion and I don't think so, I think such a conversion should be considered as `Identity conversion`. IMHO, For "S1 and S2 differ only in their qualification conversion". In order to determine whether the sentence has benn satisfied, we should agree `S1` and `S2` all have a propertity, that is `qualification conversion`, Right? Otherwise,  I say,  Animal and wood differ only in their hands. That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: This answer was mentioned in the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72917101/what-does-mean-by-s1-is-a-proper-subsequence-of-s2) resulting in conflicting answers for OP. Reading through it, I don't understand either why 3.2.1 supposedly doesn't apply for `f`. Ignoring lvalue transformations the conversion sequence for #3 is empty and that for #4 contains a single qualification conversion. Therefore the sequence for #3 is a proper subsequence for of the one for #4. The rest of 3.2. shouldn't apply because it is qualified with "_or, if not that,_".