# Is an identity conversion of pointer type be considered as qualification conversion when ranking

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
void fun(int*);  // #1
void fun(int const*);  //#2
int main(){
  int* ptr = nullptr;
  fun(ptr);
}
```

Consider the above example, the overload resolution shall select the best viable function in `#1` and `#2`.  This is a branch of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65247901/how-to-compare-two-standard-conversion-sequences-use-the-rank-of-contained-conve), namely, the vague between [over.ics.rank#3.2.1] and [over.ics.rank#3.2.5].

The relevant rules are:

[over.ics.rank#3.2.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.1)

> S1 is a proper subsequence of S2 (comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form defined by [over.ics.scs], excluding any Lvalue Transformation; **the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence**) or, if not that

IMO, `S1` of `#1` has an identity conversion while `S2` of `#2` has a qualification conversion, the above rule seems to say that `Identity conversion` is better than any non-identity conversion that has an exact match rank.

However, there's another relevant rule correspond to this case, that is:
[over.ics.rank#3.2.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.rank#3.2.5)

> S1 and S2 differ only in their qualification conversion ([conv.qual]) and yield similar types T1 and T2, respectively, where T1 can be converted to T2 by a qualification conversion.

IMO, this rule seems to say `S1` and `S2` all have a **qualification conversion** but these conversions are different and `T1` can be converted to `T2` by a qualification conversion.

In my example, from `int*` to `int const*` is absolutely a **qualification conversion**. However, an edge-case is from `int*` to `int*`, Is this conversion be considered as an identity conversion or qualification conversion?  According to the definition of [conv.qual#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#3), it could be. However, strictly speaking, it should be called **Identity conversion**.

#### Question 1:

Is my understanding of the rule [over.ics.rank#3.2.5] right?  Or, Does it mean, `S1` maybe have an empty conversion(e.g identity conversion) when `T1` can be converted to `T2` by qualification conversion? (include the identity conversion for pointers)

#### Qquestion 2:

Is an identity conversion of a pointer type be considered as a qualification conversion or just an identity conversion? In other words, Whether [over.ics.rank#3.2.1] or [over.ics.rank#3.2.5] apply to my example?

Comment: I recommend linking to the [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65247901) that inspired your question. Such attribution is good practice in general. It provides readers with useful context in which to understand your question, and can help clarify which parts of the standard rules you are having difficulties understanding. This can lead to more tailored, higher quality answers, which improves the quality of the entire Q&A.

Comment: @cigien Yes, a good suggestion. I was going to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it improves the question considerably.

Comment: @cigien I think this question is an edge-case. Maybe, [over.ics.rank#3.2.1] and [over.ics.rank#3.2.5] all can process this overload resolution. Merely, [over.ics.rank#3.2.1] first apply to this case. This is my opinion about the discussion between you and mine for that  [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65247901/how-to-compare-two-standard-conversion-sequences-use-the-rank-of-contained-conve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard conversion sequence from `int*` to `int*` does **not** contain a qualification conversion.

This is made explicit by [over.ics.best.general]/8:

> If no conversions are required to match an argument to a parameter type, the implicit conversion sequence is the standard conversion sequence consisting of the identity conversion ([over.ics.scs]).

It can also be inferred from other paragraphs. For example, see [over.best.ics.general]/1:

> An implicit conversion sequence is a sequence of conversions used to convert an argument in a function call to the type of the corresponding parameter of the function being called.
> The sequence of conversions is an implicit conversion as defined in [conv], which means it is governed by the rules for initialization of an object or reference by a single expression ([dcl.init], [dcl.init.ref]).

and [over.ics.best.general]/6:

> When the parameter type is not a reference, the implicit conversion sequence models a copy-initialization of the parameter from the argument expression.
> The implicit conversion sequence is the one required to convert the argument expression to a prvalue of the type of the parameter.
> ...

That is, the correct implicit conversion sequence for `int*` -> `int*` is the one that, according to the rules of the language, is normally formed when `int*` is copy-initialized from `int*`. In this case, [dcl.init.general]/16.9 applies:

> Otherwise, the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the initializer expression.
> A standard conversion sequence ([conv]) will be used, if necessary, to convert the initializer expression to the cv-unqualified version of the destination type; no user-defined conversions are considered.
> If the conversion cannot be done, the initialization is ill-formed.
> When initializing a bit-field with a value that it cannot represent, the resulting value of the bit-field is implementation-defined.

No conversion is *necessary* since `int*` and `int*` are already the same type, so no conversion is done. It is not a qualification conversion from `int*` to itself.

This means [over.ics.rank]/3.2.1 is certainly dispositive: `S1` is the identity conversion sequence (not an implicit conversion sequence consisting of a redundant qualification conversion) so it's a subsequence of `S2`.

Comment: Thanks, your understanding is almost the same as mine. However, for [dcl.init.general]/16.9, even the target type is the same as the source type, I think `lvalue-to-rvalue` conversion still applies to the source initializer in order to read the value(evaluate prvalue will initialize the result object ). Or  `int* const` to `int*`.(lvalue-to-rvalue still apply to). However, as [over.ics.rank#3.2.1] says, `lvalue-to-rvalue` does not participate in the evaluation of the ranking. So, `lvalue-to-rvalue` does not affect the ranking